# how to create oblique cylinder

Tags: image, 3d, structure, skew

how to create a oblique solid cylinder that cross x axis(OR OTHERS) 45 degree
this is my code, but it only a line pic 
where does it error 
create
a radius =0.5
H=3
cross x axis 45 degree

```
R =0.2 ;           % Radius of the cylindrical shell
H =3 ;           % Height of the Cylinder
M = 1000 ;N = 1000 ;
x=[];y=[];z=[];dz=0;
% Discretizing the Height and Angle of the cylinder
nH = linspace(0,H,M) ;
nT = linspace(0,2*pi,N) ;
[H, T] = meshgrid(nH,nT) ;
%% cylinder at (0,0)
X1 = R*cos(T); 
Y1 = R*sin(T);
Z1 = --2.36*sind(R)
surf(X1,Y1,Z1)
```

ths u